# TypeORM: Test wheter my Models are in sync with a Database

Tags: typeorm

It there a way without synchronizing(touching/modifying my database) to know/test if my Models are in sync with the database schema?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to generate a migration file with the following command:

```
typeorm migration:generate
```

If your database differs from your entities a file is generated, otherwise TypeORM will tell you that you are up to date. See [docs](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/migrations.md#generating-migrations) for details.